Firestore deserialization error: "Unable to create converter for type UserCustomData" in C# .NET application
I'm working with Firestore in a C# .NET application, and I'm encountering a deserialization error when trying to convert Firestore documents into instances of my custom class, UserCustomData. Despite having a public parameterless constructor and public properties, I receive the following error message:
Unhandled exception has occurred in your application.
Unable to create converter for type RepoGen.Classes.UserCustomData.
Here's the relevant portion of my UserCustomData class:
public class UserCustomData
{
    public UserCustomData() { } 

    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }    
}

And here's how I'm attempting to fetch and convert the Firestore document:
`public static async Task<UserCustomData> GetUserAsync(string uid)
{
    DocumentReference docRef = Database.Collection("users").Document(uid);
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await docRef.GetSnapshotAsync();
    if (snapshot.Exists)
    {
        UserCustomData userCustomData = snapshot.ConvertTo<UserCustomData>();
        return userCustomData;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}`

I have confirmed that the fields in the Firestore document exactly match the property names in the class, including casing, and the Firestore document structure is simple, with no nested objects
I have also ensured the Google.Cloud.Firestore NuGet package is installed and up-to-date.
Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting this error and how to resolve it?

Two issues I observed in relation to this error:
1 - The user class needs to be annotated as follows:
[FirestoreData]
public class UserCustomData
{
    [FirestoreProperty(nameof(Username))]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [FirestoreProperty(nameof(Email))]
    public string Email { get; set; }    
}

In my case, I found class annotation to be mandatory, but it worked ok without property annotations.
2 - The error also occurs if data types don't match. e.g. if a field is specified as int and the data from Firestore is a sting. Unlikely in your case, but it is worth checking.

As fas as I understand, "nameof" is not necessary. Maybe it is necessary for non-identical property names.
